# Alert Filters not getting applied

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, alert, sharepoint-on-prem

I am trying to Export the alerts of a site and import them to another using Powershell.

It is working perfectly except filters. They are not getting applied.

Any ideas, please.

script attached :

NOTE : All the items  I am picking form csv.

```
    $user = $web.EnsureUser($item.User)
    $alert = $user.Alerts.Add()
    $alert.Title = $item.Title
    $alert.DeliveryChannels = $item.DeliveryChannel
    $alert.EventType = $item.EventType
    $alert.AlertFrequency = $item.Frequency
    if($item.AlertType -eq "List")
    {
        $alert.AlertType = $item.AlertType  
        $alert.List = $web.Lists[$item.List]
    }
    elseif($item.AlertType -eq "Item")
    {
        $alert.AlertType = $item.AlertType
        $list = $web.Lists[$item.List]
        $item = $list.Items.GetItemById($item.Item)
        $alert.Item = $item
    }
    $alert.Filter=$item.Filter 
    $alert.Update()
```

Comment: Please share your current tries (PowerShell script) to can help you faster!

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP  script is updated .

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP script is updated.

Comment: Sorry bro, let me check it

Comment: Just in case any progress @MohamedEl-QassasMVP

Comment: what's the value of $item.Filter?

Comment: Suppose I have specified that send the alert when someone else has made changes, than on exporting the alert the value for filter will be <Query><Neq><Value type="string">UserName</Value><FieldRef Name="Editor/New"/></Neq></Query>